# Can I upload files to google cloud storage from url?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Code Exemple:

```
gsutil cp "http://www.exemple.com/file.txt" "gs://bucket/"
```

Comment: Really good question... I've read literally every where I could and haven't found a answer to this either... does anyone know?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can stream the output of curl to the gsutil cp command as follows:

```
curl http://www.example.com/file.txt | gsutil cp - gs://bucket/file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple and neat solution.

Answer (score 10):

There is [Cloud Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/) with [an option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/#urls) to upload list of 
URLs though not very simple and more batch-oriented.

Comment: Looks like this method requires MD5 hash of the source files

Comment: Transfer Service asks for very silly parameters: size and MD5, both should not be required there

Comment: For a newcomer this looks like a super complicated process for such a simple task

Answer (score 1):

For wget:

```
wget http://www.example.com/file.txt -O - | gsutil cp - gs://bucket/file.txt
```