# Why Transfer in GCP failed on csv file and where is the error log?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, data-transfer

I am testing out the transfer function in GCP:

This is the open data in csv, https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Annual-enterprise-survey/Annual-enterprise-survey-2018-financial-year-provisional/Download-data/annual-enterprise-survey-2018-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv

My configuration in GCP:

[image]

The transfer failed as below:

[image]

Question 1: why the transfer failed?

Question 2: where is the error log?

Thank you very much.

**[UPDATE]:**

I checked log history, nothing was captured:

[image]

**[Update 2]:**

Error details:

Details: First line in URL list must be TsvHttpData-1.0 but it is: Year,Industry_aggregation_NZSIOC,Industry_code_NZSIOC,Industry_name_NZSIOC,Units,Variable_code,Variable_name,Variable_category,Value,Industry_code_ANZSIC06

I noticed in the transfer service if you choose the third option for source: it reads URL of **TSV** file. Essentially TSV, PSV are just variants of CSV, and I have no problem retrieving the source csv file. The error details seem to implicating something not expected there.

Comment: Error's detected by GCP operations are logged to GCP Stackdriver logging.  What I'd suggest is looking at all the logs in Log Viewer around the time of the error and see what we see.

Comment: Thank you, nothing there, OP updated with screenshot

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with Stackdriver but your screen shot shows a very filtered set.  I'd go into advanced view and remove **all** filters and see if anything shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your example, you are pointing to a data file as the source of the transfer.  If we read the documentation on GCS transfer, we find that the we must specify a file which contains the identity of the target URL that we want to copy.

The format of this file is called a Tab-Separated-Values (TSV) and contains a number of parameters including:

1. The URL of the source of the file.
2. The size in bytes of the source file.
3. An MD5 hash of the content of the source file.

What you specified (just the URL of the source file) ... is not what is required.

One possible solution would be to use gsutil.  It has an option of taking a stream as input and writing that stream to a given object.  For example:

```
curl http://[URL]/[PATH] | gsutil cp - gs://[BUCKET]/[OBJECT]
```

References:

- [Creating a URL list](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list)
- [Can I upload files to google cloud storage from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107545/can-i-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-url)

Comment: Thanks. My comment overlapped with your answer. I will try it again.

Comment: hmm, I don't get this at all. Per the instruction I need to provide size and MD5 hash, Why must I provide these two as input parameters? An URL should be the only thing needed to retrieve it. is there any reason that size and MD5 are required? How do I get the size in bytes of the source file (Other than download it locally), The link you provided describes a very tedious process in my opinion and I am very surprised of it.

Comment: @mdivk ... I don't disagree :-) ... I think there should be an option where one can specify a source URL and whatever is found there is copies/streamed to the target GCS object.  However ... our reality is simply that isn't there.  What we could do is raise an enhancement request with Google to have something added.    Alternatively, you could patch together a solution using the gsutil command (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107545/can-i-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-url)

Comment: Cool, that workaround is like a amazing trick, 4M in one tick tak, done. Thank you. Please kindly modify your answer and add that trick in, I will happily accept it as the answer.

Comment: Glad that worked for you!!  And thank you for posting great questions to Stackoverflow!!

Comment: What does "4M in one tick tak" mean?