# Google Cloud Storage upload using link

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I can successfully upload file in the Google JSON API using [Objects: insert] by passing binary file content. I was curious if there is a way to upload by passing an open link in a JSON payload allowing GCP to retrieve the file. Thanks!

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890062/put-files-to-google-cloud-storage-gcs-via-signed-urls) shows you how to use Signed URLs to PUT objects in Cloud Storage via the Client Libraries. You can also use the `gsutil` to copy the content of a URL into a GCS bucket, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107545/can-i-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-url). Does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this looks promising. I'll send an update after trying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I upload files to google cloud storage from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107545/can-i-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-url)

Answer (score -1):

It seems `Signed URLs` can help you do this.

you can check here

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Looks like singed URLs are for retrieving/accessing files already in GCP. I'm looking for a way to push data to GCP by providing it a URL where the file currently lives.

Comment: You can both upload and dowload files via signedurls.