# Parallel download of images and store in GCS storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

Looking for ideas for parallel download of images based on urls (zip file) as the input. The images downloaded need to be stored in GCS buckets. I have about 6 million images to download
My initial thoughts are to run a pyspark program that runs in dataproc and downloads images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I upload files to google cloud storage from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107545/can-i-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-url)

Comment: thanks! it does! i might not be able to use a public URL list file. Thats the only limitation

Comment: There's other options, too: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/file-to-file